# sqlite windows phone 8 app example

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8

Please someone suggest me sample app for windows phone 8 using sqlite database...

I have experience with SQL CE with windows phone. I have tried to find example for sqlite but all I can find is Apps with complex coding using mvvm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Articles

- You can look at the excellent tutorial - http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_use_SQLite_in_Windows_Phone
- Windows phone has another good article about it - http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/03/12/using-the-sqlite-database-engine-with-windows-phone-8-apps.aspx
- With MVVM - http://www.spikie.be/blog/post/2013/01/29/SQLite-in-Windows-Phone-8.aspx

### Code Sample

- MSDN Code sample - http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Using-Sqlite-with-WP8-52c3c671